# How to chunk properly a query with subquery in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, subquery

My problem is that I need to get at any moment the duplicate entries on mel column from dest table.

I've tried so many things to translate this query in Laravel but couldn't find the way :

```
select id
from dest d,
     (select mel from dest where stt = 0 group by mel having count(mel) > 1) sr
where d.mel = sr.mel
```

I've tried to create a view

```
create DEFINER = user view dest_doubles
```

as select id from dest d, (select mel from dest where stt = 0 group by mel having count(mel) > 1) sr where d.mel = sr.mel

The `select id from dest_doubles` query lasts forever whereas

```
select id from dest d, (select mel from dest where stt = 0 group by
mel having count(mel) > 1) sr where d.mel = sr.mel
```

responds in 3 minutes

I've tried this in Laravel command :

```
\DB::select(\DB::raw('dest.id'))
                        ->from(\DB::raw('dest, (select mel from dest where stt = 0 group by mel having count(mel) > 1) as sr'))
                        ->whereRaw('dest.mel = sr.mel')
                        ->chunk(10000, function ($doubles) {
```

});

And could not execute :

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dest.id' at
>   line 1

So I don't know how to chunk a query that contains a subquery in Laravel

Thank you for helping

Comment: I should precise that dest is a big table with 8 millions rows

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Laravel guru, but you can rewrite your original query as an `INNER JOIN` between your table and the subquery.  This might be easier using Laravel.

```
SELECT id
FROM dest d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT mel
    FROM dest
    WHERE stt = 0
    GROUP BY mel
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS sr
    ON d.mel = sr.mel
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply !
I've tried to execute directly from MySQL before implementing your idea but it's quite long and lasting.. I guess because it's a big table (around 8m rows)